# How to add text before and next to progress bar bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add some text before `and` next to a progress bar in bootstrap. The way I want it to look is the follow:

```
<div class="project-container">               
<h4 class="progress-label">Java</h4>    
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"
       style="width: 60%;">         
    </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/ymqkhury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an `inline` element with a float to left

**[Example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/sxkypn36)**

You also might want to increase the height of the bar to 18 pixels to match the title and the bar. Or decrease the `line-height` of the title.

Answer (score 0):

just do a table around it:

```
<center>
                  <div style=max-width:460px;>

                                <div class="row">
                                <div class=col-xs-12>

                                <p>
                                    <span class="pull-left"><strong>3456 Punti Esperienza</strong></span>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Completato</span>
                                </p>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class=row>
                                <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <span class="label label-primary">Liv. 4</span>
                                </div><div class=col-xs-10>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <span class="label label-success pull-right">Liv. 5</span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </center>
```

see the example here http://jsfiddle.net/00gftvkm/